# Make Error/Linking Error

Tags: c++, makefile

i just started to use Linux... so maybe thats a newbie questions, but google couldnt help me.
I started with the book "Test Driven Development". The first task is to build some files with cmake and after that you should execute them with "make".

The cmake part is working but the make part fails.
This is my error

```
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test.dir/SoundexTest.cpp.o
In file included from /home/balu/TDD/gmock-1.6.0/gtest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-linked_ptr.h:74:0,
..
bla
..
Linking CXX executable test
/home/balu/TDD/gmock-1.6.0/mybuild/libgmock.a(gmock-all.cc.o): In function `testing::internal::ThreadLocal<testing::Sequence*>::CreateKey()':
..
bla
..
gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZNK7testing8internal11ThreadLocalIPNS_31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceEE16GetOrCreateValueEv[_ZNK7testing8internal11ThreadLocalIPNS_31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceEE16GetOrCreateValueEv]+0x7a): undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I hope you can give me a hint what is wrong

greets

Comment: You apparently missed to compile and link using the `-pthread` compiler/linker flag.

Comment: I think this is done in the cmake file: target_link_libraries(test pthread)

Comment: No, `-pthread` isn't automatically added using `target_link_libraries(test gtest)`. It should appear in the `CXX_FLAGS` build variable.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You should probably add that as an answer.

Comment: or, if you want to be more generic, you can use find_package(Threads): see here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindThreads.html